# how to simplify my php code(insert, update and delete)

Tags: php, mysql, function

Hi I am a newbie in PHP I heard that there is a way on how to simplify your php query code :)

First I want to simplify insert:

1. I have a query `mysql_query("insert into table (`sample`) values ('$sample')");`
   I want to simplify it like a formula you just enter the table and the values just it. so that whenever I query I will not type mysql_query blah blah blah
2. Next Selecting data on database. Like `mysql_query(select * from account where contatc='$contatc')` I want to simplify it or just make a formula whenever I will query it I will not type anymore.

I also read that in order to make it I will use functions
Thanks in advance

This is an example on selecting data

```
function check($value, $where, $database) {
    //foreach($field_arr as $value);
    $q=sprintf("SELECT `".$value."` FROM `".$database."` WHERE ".$where."");
    if(! $data=mysql_query($q)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return mysql_num_rows($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very dangerous as is.  There's no apparent protection against sql injection because you're building a query string from arbitrary input. Also, you're using the mysql_* functions which are deprecated and not maintained.  Their use introduces a whole class of other potential risks, and when they're eventually removed from PHP your code will break.  You should switch to mysqli or PDO as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the functions to perform database operations

```
## Connect to Server ##
    function connect($server="",$user="", $pass="")
    {
        $conn = mysql_pconnect($server,$user,$pass);
        if(!$conn) {
            echo "Connection attempt failed"." Error No:".mysql_errno()."<br>Error Message : ". mysql_error();
        }
        return true;
    }

    ## Select Database for table operation ##
    function selectDatabase($dbase)
    {
        global $conn;
        if(empty($conn)) { echo "Connection not found"; }

        if(!mysql_select_db($dbase, $conn)) {
            echo "Dbase Select failed"." Error No:".mysql_errno()."<br>Error Message : ". mysql_error();
        }
    }

    ## Execute Select Query
    function select ($sql="", $fetch = "mysql_fetch_assoc")
    {
        global $conn;
        if(empty($sql)) { echo "Select Query not found"; }
        if(empty($conn)) { echo "Connection not found";}
        $results = @mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(!$results) {
            echo "Error in Query : ".$sql."<br>".mysql_errno()." : ". mysql_error();
        }
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $fetch($results))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        mysql_free_result($results);
        return $data;
    }

    ## Execute Insert Query
    function insert ($sql="")
    {
        global $conn;
        if(empty($sql)) { echo "Insert query not found"; }

        if(empty($conn)
        {
            echo "Connection not found";
        }

        $results = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(!$results)
        {
            echo "Error in Query : ".$sql."<br>".mysql_errno()." : ". mysql_error();
        }
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        If($id)
            return $id;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    ## Execute Update / Delete / mulitple insert query
    function execute($sql="")
    {
        global $conn;
        if(empty($sql)) { echo "Query not found"; }
        if(empty($conn))
        {
            echo "Connection not found";
        }

        $results = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(!$results)
        {
            echo "Error in Query : ".$sql."<br>".mysql_errno()." : ". mysql_error();
        }
        $rows = 0;
        $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
        if($rows==0)    return 1;
        return $rows;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware with your code. With this code, it's really easy to add SQL injection to it. And you have another problem: you are using the mysql_* extensions, which are totally deprecated (they will be removed in the next main release of PHP).

My advice is:

- Switch to another DB library. I recommend PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but you can also use mysqli.
- Learn a bit about SQL injection. There are lots of good and interesting threads here in Stack Overflow talking about SQL injection and PHP.